# Razor.ServiceStack - How to set a cookie that expires in 90 days

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack

I'm using Service Stack Razor to develop a SPA application.

Is it possible to set a cookie that expires in 90 days, which can also be used with 'RememberMe' of /auth/credentials ?

I'm also having a challenge understanding how to properly use 'RememberMe' property of /auth/credentials, as I've not been able to find any clear examples of how to properly apply the logic.

So, does the "RememberMe" propery really work as it does in traditional ASP.NET applications (Forms) or am I just wishing.

Please Advise.

P.S. Bare-bone simple example snippets are greatly appreciated.